# Test case for a trans?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have the transfer method in the service class and I would like to create a test for this method, to check if the transfer value is valid.

The method I would like to test is this:

```
public void transfer(Account destiny, double value) {
        Account origin = new Account();
        if (value<= origin.getBalance()) {
            this.withdraw(value);
            destiny.setDeposit(value);
        }
    }
```

I am now starting to tinker with tests. thanks for the comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

I would first recommend that you refactor that method.
Instead of instantiating/creating/finding the origin account inside the method, you want to pass that in.
So your new method signature should look as following

```
public void transfer(Account destiny, Account origin, double value) {
   ...
}
```

Once that's done your happy path test case should look something like this

```
Account destiny = new Account();
destiny.setBalance(100); // Some way to set balance
Account origin = new Account();
origin.setBalance(75); // Some way to set balance

transfer(destiny,origin,25); //Call your method

assertEquals(origin.getBalance(), 50);
assertEquals(origin.getBalance(), 125);
```

You can also test the negative case here where the origin balance is less than the transfer amount so the transfer doesn't happen and the balance on both accounts is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, check the balance has changed

```java
Account origin = new Account();
double originBalance = origin.getBalance();

transfer(destiny, value);

Account current = new Account();
double currentBalance = current.getBalance();

// Balance should have changed
assertNotEquals(originBalance, currentBalance, 1e-15);
```